# TCalendarPicker not styled (Delphi 10.4)

Tags: delphi, vcl, vcl-styles, delphi-10.4-sydney

The ~new TCalendarPicker control does not seem to change with a VCL style, is this as designed or maybe it can be fixed through [RRUZ' vcl-styles-utils](https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-utils)?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can add a tag for the Delphi version you call "~new" today, it might not be so new after a year or two. And, sorry, I don't have the 10.4 release, so can't help you.

Comment: 10.4 introduces a new [per-control styling](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/What%27s_New#VCL_Per_Control_Styling) feature.  Maybe you accidentally disabled styling for the calendar?  Or, maybe it simply wasn't updated in 10.4 to support the new feature yet?  Who knows.  You can always [file a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com).

Comment: All the style elements are enabled.